# Spring MVC + Jackson - JsonView

Tags: java, json, spring

I need to expose two different set of values from my model, so i implemented 2 views

```
public class Views {

    public static class Small{ }

    public static class Large extends Small { }

}
```

Then, in my model i put (all other fields are annotated with JSONIgnore

```
@JsonView(Views.Small.class)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_posto", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdPosto() {
        return this.idPosto;
    }

    public void setIdPosto(int idPosto) {
        this.idPosto = idPosto;
    }

@JsonView(Views.Large.class)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nome_posto_park")
    public String getNomePosto() {
        return this.nomePosto;
    }
public void setNomePosto(String nomePosto) {
        this.nomePosto = nomePosto;
    }
```

On my Controllers I have 2 methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/spots", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Posto> getSpotStatus(@RequestParam(value = "idPosto") int idPosto,
            @RequestParam(value = "occupied") boolean occupied) {
        Posto posto = postoService.findByIdPosto(idPosto);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                .withView(Views.Small.class));
        mapper.convertValue(posto, JsonNode.class);

return new ResponseEntity<Posto>(posto, HttpStatus.OK);
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/spot", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Posto>> getSpotList(@RequestParam (value = "idPiano") int idPiano){
        Piano piano = pianoService.findById(idPiano);

    List<Posto> posti = postoService.showSpotsByFloor(-1, piano);
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                .withView(Views.Large.class));
    mapper.convertValue(posti, JsonNode.class);

    return new ResponseEntity<List<Posto>>(posti, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Che result is the same... (obviously the first is a single Posto and the second a List but all the fields from the model are serialized....

What I'm doing wrong when using views?

Answer (score 0):

You need define produces and consume with agree view and annotation with @ResponseBody

Example: Change your needed

```
@Produces(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
@Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody   public ResponseEntity<List<Posto>> getSpotList(...

//when request, put your client agree request view
protected HttpEntity<T> headers()
{
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    headers.set("application", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    // T define your type here
    return new HttpEntity<T>(headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Spring instantiates its own Jackson `ObjectMapper` when the `ApplicationContext` starts.

You'll have to autowire the Spring managed `ObjectMapper` and configure that instance instead of creating your own with `new`.

```
private final ObjectMapper mapper;

public MyController(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
}
```